# Enable root login from GUI

Tags: linux-mint, login, root, lightdm, autologin

I just installed Mint 16 and I see that root user is not available at login screen. I log in from normal user and went to "Login Window" option and there I set "Allow root login". Then I restarted the PC and still I don't see root user in login window.

I also did the below but it also didn't work.

```
sudo passwd root
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to log in as Root on a GUI? There's good reason why they make it so hard to do, and you're doing something seriously wrong if you think you require it.

Comment: On some systems and DEs, only users above UID 1000 (conventionally, non-system users) are displayed by the login manager. This is also why you don't see `postfix`, `www-data`, `mail` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux Mint 16 uses the Mint-X theme by default which only displays the password box for chosen non-root users.  In order to enable the `User` entry field (from which you will be able to specify root) do this.  From `Menu` ==> `Administration` ==> `Login Window` ==> `Theme` choose `Clouds` and logout.

Comment: I changed to `Clouds`, still I don't see the root user there.

Comment: When you login, it is necessary to enter the username root, followed by the password.  The user root doesn't show in the list of users but you will be able to login as root this way.

Comment: Actually it doesn't show the `username` field. I pressed `ESC` and it appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Usual warnings of root login is dangerous, do not use unless you are expert.

Linux Mint Rebecca 17.1 uses nemo desktop as do others. root login text has been moved to: `/usr/share/mdm/defaults.conf` line 185.
those who don't know how, this is what to do.

Open Terminal and type `sudo passwd root` you will be prompted for a new root password.

Next type, `sudo gedit /usr/share/mdm/defaults.conf` the file will open in read/write mode fr editing. hit  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to search for root login it will highlight in yellow, change false to true and save. reboot to greeter with root login.

Comment: [security]
# Allow root to login.  It makes sense to turn this off for kiosk use, when
# you want to minimize the possibility of break in.
AllowRoot=true

Answer (score 0):

You can root the system via terminal, so that you get total access to everything. The first thing you need to do is to change the type of user you are, if you open the terminal, you're probably going to see this symbol next to your user-name: $. If you were a *su* (super user), the symbol you would see would be this one: #. 
To become a *su* you'll have to change the *su* password by typing `sudo passwd root`. Now it will ask you to create a new password, and confirm it twice. Once you're down, you just have to type `su -` and then enter the password you changed before. That's it, you now have total access to everything.

Comment: Just a quick word about terminology. The command `/usr/bin/su` is called _substitute user_ or colloquially _switch user_. It is not specifically intended for only switching to the **root** account. Also, the term **superuser** is quite common in *NIX and other systems, but it is not really part of the default group names in most distributions (all distros that I know of...we call it _superuser_ but I've never seen it in the system itself).